# Automate Google Sheets to strings.xml for localization

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets of the translations of all my strings.xml resources. Each language is a column. And the first column is the string resource ID.

Do you know of a tool that I can use to (or a macro or anything) that will let me re-export my spreadsheet into a strings.xml format with the appropriate territory suffix? (The suffixes are the first row of the spreadsheet.)

Comment: The solution I came up with was to export the spreadsheet as CSV and then write an actionscript program that broke the CSV into XML and saved it to files for each territory. There were a few problems whtn the translation included a comma. But that left only about 5 fields to do by hand instead of 76.

Comment: I think you can choose the delimiting character in excel when you export it. I know for sure it supports tab as a delimiter which would've gotten you around the comma issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that will work in a lot of cases. Yours may vary.

1. I exported the as CSV (Comma Separated values).
2. I imported the CSV into a flash movie as text.
3. I parsed each row of the CSV into an array by slitting the text file on new line. "\n"
4. Then I looped through the rows, grabbing the value for each language.

My spreadsheet column heading were

```
name,plural value,en,fr,de,it,es,ja
```

Below is the code I used. It has two shortcomings that you may need to apply to your own spreadsheet. First, it does not handle plural values. It just makes duplicate string entries that you then need to go back and edit by hand. Second, if your text being translated contains commas, actionscript will split the string on those commas instead of at the end of each section. I noticed afterwards that Excel wraps values with double quotes if they contain commas. Not sure what it would do if they contained commas and double quotes, though. If your text has cases like these, you will need to add some code to handle these cases. But below is my Actionscript code that I used.

When you compile and run the swf, there will be a yellow button. Click that and it will offer to save one of the languages. Each time you click it will save out a different language. And it loops back to the first language if you keep clicking and so on.

But the end output should be very close to a perfect translation strings.xml

**The Main Class:**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Plastic Sturgeon
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var rows:Array;
        private var en:XML = <resources></resources>;
        private var fr:XML = <resources></resources>;
        private var de:XML = <resources></resources>;
        private var it:XML = <resources></resources>;
        private var es:XML = <resources></resources>;
        private var xmls:Vector.<XML> = new Vector.<XML>;

        private var counter:uint = 0;
        public function Main():void 
        {
            xmls.push(en);
            xmls.push(fr);
            xmls.push(de);
            xmls.push(it);
            xmls.push(es);

            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            dumpIt();
            graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
        }

        private function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var language:int = counter % 5;
            var suffixes:Array = new Array("en", "fr", "de", "it", "es");
            var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            ba.writeObject('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r'+xmls[language].toXMLString());    
            fr.save(ba, "strings-"+suffixes[language]+".xml");
            counter++
        }
        public function dumpIt():void
        {
            var obj:EmbeddedText = new EmbeddedText();
            //txt.text = obj.toString();
            rows = obj.toString().split("\r");
            trace(rows.length);
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {
                var row:Array = String(rows[i]).split(",");
                for (var j:uint = 0; j < xmls.length; j++ ) {
                    var name:String = row[0]
                    name = name.substring(1);
                    var value:String = row[2 + j];                  
                    var node:XML = new XML('<string name="' + name + '">' + value + '</string>');
                    //trace('<string name="' + name + '">' + value + '</string>');
                    xmls[j].appendChild(node);
                }
            }
            trace("en",en);
        }
    }

}
```

**The embeded text class to compile your text file into the swf:**

```
package  
{
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Plastic Sturgeon
     */
    [Embed(source="translateion_csv.txt", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    public class EmbeddedText extends ByteArray
    {

        public function EmbeddedText() 
        {

        }

    }
}
```

and finally: here is a sampling of the text I translated, for you to test out on your own:

```
name,plural value,en,fr,de,it,es,ja
homescreen_new_button,,NEW TOURNAMENT,NOUVEAU TOURNOI,NEUES TURNIER,NUOVO TORNEO,NUEVO TORNEO,
homescreen_current_button,,VIEW CURRENT BRACKET,VOIR LE TABLEAU ACTUEL,AKTUELLER TURNIERSTAND,VISUALIZZA GRIGLIA,VER NIVEL ACTUAL,
tournament_type_title,,TOURNAMENT SETTINGS,PARAMÈTRES DU TOURNOI,TURNIER-EINSTELLUNGEN,IMPOSTAZIONI TORNEO,CONFIGURACIÓN DE TORNEO,
tournament_type_gaming_stations,,HOW MANY GAMING STATIONS,COMBIEN DE POSTES,WIE VIELE SPIELGERÄTE,NUMERO DI POSTAZIONI DI GIOCO,NÚMERO DE MÁQUINAS DE JUEGO,
tournament_type_tournament_type,,TOURNAMENT TYPE,TYPE DE TOURNOI,TURNIERART,TIPO DI TORNEO,TIPO DE TORNEO,
tournament_type_tournament_type_single,,SINGLE ELIMINATION,ÉLIMINATION DIRECTE,EINFACHE ELIMINIERUNG,ELIMINAZIONE SINGOLA,ELIMINACIÓN INDIVIDUAL,
tournament_type_tournament_type_double,,DOUBLE ELIMINATION,DOUBLE ÉLIMINATION,DOPPELTE ELIMINIERUNG,ELIMINAZIONE DOPPIA,ELIMINACIÓN DOBLE,
tournament_type_back_warning_title,,WARNING,AVERTISSEMENT,ACHTUNG,AVVISO,ATENCIÓN,
tournament_type_back_warning_message,,Going back to the home screen will clear all information.\nDo you want to continue?,Retourner à l\'écran d\'accueil effacera toutes les données.\nVoulez-vous continuer ?,Durch die Rückkehr zum Home-Bildschirm werden alle Informationen gelöscht.\nWirklich fortfahren?,Tornando alla schermata iniziale perderai tutte le informazioni.\nVuoi continuare?,"Si vuelves a la pantalla principal, se borrará toda la información.\n¿Continuar?",
tournament_type_back_warning_confirm,,OK,OK,OK,OK,Aceptar,
tournament_type_back_warning_cancel,,Cancel,Annuler,Abbrechen,Annulla,Cancelar,
tournament_type_help_single,,Players are eliminated after their first loss.,Les joueurs sont éliminés dès la première défaite.,Spieler scheiden nach ihrer ersten Niederlage aus.,I giocatori vengono eliminati dopo la prima sconfitta.,Los jugadores quedan eliminados a la primera derrota.,
tournament_type_help_double,,"After a player loses once, they enter the Loser\'s bracket.  They are eliminated if they lose a second time.","Après une première défaite, le joueur intègre le tableau des perdants. Il est éliminé s\'il perd une seconde fois.",Nach einer ersten Niederlage nimmt der Spieler an der Verliererrunde teil. Bei einer zweiten Niederlage scheidet er aus.,"Dopo una sconfitta, i giocatori vengono inseriti nella griglia sconfitti. Vengono eliminati se perdono per la seconda volta.","Al perder una vez, pasan al nivel de perdedores. Si pierden una segunda vez, quedan eliminados.",
add_players_title,,ADD PLAYERS,AJOUTER DES JOUEURS,SPIELER HINZUFÜGEN,AGGIUNGI GIOCATORI,AÑADIR JUGADORES,
add_players_seed,,SEED,CLASSER,SETZEN,TESTA DI SERIE,CABEZA DE SERIE,
add_players_delete,,DELETE,SUPPRIMER,LÖSCHEN,CANCELLA,QUITAR,
add_players_default_value,,PLAYER NAME,NOM DU JOUEUR,SPIELERNAME,NOME GIOCATORE,NOMBRE DE JUGADOR,
add_players_dialog_title,,ADD PLAYER,AJOUTER UN JOUEUR,SPIELER HINZUFÜGEN,AGGIUNGI GIOCATORE,AÑADIR JUGADOR,
add_players_dialog_message,,ENTER THE PLAYER NAME,ENTRER LE NOM DU JOUEUR,SPIELERNAMEN EINGEBEN,INSERISCI IL NOME DEL GIOCATORE,ESCRIBE EL NOMBRE DE JUGADOR,
add_players_dialog_OK,,OK,OK,OK,OK,ACEPTAR,
add_players_dialog_ok_and_add,,OK + ADD ANOTHER,OK + EN AJOUTER UN AUTRE,OK + MEHR HINZUFÜGEN,OK + AGGIUNGI ALTRO,ACEPTAR Y AÑADIR OTRO,
add_players_dialog_cancel,,CANCEL,ANNULER,ABBRECHEN,ANNULLA,CANCELAR,
add_players_dialog_name_taken,,Name Already Taken,Nom déjà utilisé,Name bereits vergeben,Nome già in uso,Nombre ya utilizado,
add_players_dialog_name_added,,Player Added,Joueur ajouté,Spieler hinzugefügt,Giocatore aggiunto,Jugador añadido,
add_players_delete_confirm,,DELETE,SUPPRIMER,LÖSCHEN,CANCELLA,QUITAR,
add_players_delete_cancel,,DONE,TERMINÉ,FERTIG,FATTO,HECHO,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula `=CONCATENATE("<string name=",char(34),A2,char(34),">",E2,"</string>")`  where A2 is the resource ID and E2 is the language you have translated

Copy the column and paste it inside your `<resources>_</resources>` tag

Comment: Thanks! great solution! even better formula would be `=CONCATENATE("<string name=",char(34),$A2,char(34),">",E2,"</string>")` now it can be simply expanded to next columns  (useful when you have many languages translations in same sheet) as well!

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps:

1. Export the spreadsheet as **Open Office**
2. unzip it
3. get the `content.xml` file
4. parse and/or translate it
5. generate different `strings.xml` files

Alternatively, you may use [PyUNO](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html#intro) to extract the content from the OOo document.

Comment: step 4 would be more work than doing it all by hand, I fear. But thanks for taking the time to answer.